# How to add custom amount and email values to Paystack

Tags: angular, email, ionic-framework, initialization, ionic4

I am building an ionic 4 angular app in which I have integrated a paystack payment gateway. The default amount specified is NGR 5000 and the default email is users@gmail.com. I want to dynamically change the amount and email so that the email is equal to (this.data.emailaddress) where (this.data.email address) is the value of email address passed down to the current page from another page.
Every effort has proven abortive for over four days now.
one of the errors I've been getting is "property "data" is used before its initialization".
I have tried to declare data at oninit, at export, and immediately under the constructor yet no luck.
I've tried a lot of other options, please any help would be appreciated.
please pardon my crude method of code I'm still new in programming.

please take a look at my codes:

paytackpayment.ts

```
   import { DataitemsService } from './../dataitems.service';
   import { ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts/ngx';
   import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

   import {observable,Subscription} from 'rxjs';
   import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

   import{ProfilePage}from '../Profile/profile.page';

   import { send } from 'process';

   import * as firebase from 'firebase';
   import 'firebase/firestore'
   import { ProfilePageModule } from '../profile/profile.module';
   import { promise } from 'protractor';
   import { async } from 'rxjs/internal/scheduler/async';


   import { PaystackOptions } from 'angular4-paystack';

   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
   import {Router}from '@angular/router';

   import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
   import { NewmenuPage } from './../newmenu/newmenu.page';

   import {AlertController} from '@ionic/angular';
   import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
   import { FormGroup, FormBuilder,FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
   import { AngularFirestore,AngularFirestoreCollection} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
   import { splitNsName } from '@angular/compiler';

   import{ NavParams} from '@ionic/angular';
   import{NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
   import {ActivatedRoute, NavigationExtras}from '@angular/router';
   import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

   import { Message } from '@angular/compiler/src/i18n/i18n_ast';


  @Component({
      selector: 'app-paystackpayment',
      templateUrl: './paystackpayment.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./paystackpayment.page.scss'],
    })
    export class PaystackpaymentPage implements OnInit {
      data: any;
        service: any;
    
        detail: any;
        firestore: any;
  
        user: any;
        name: any;
    
        doc:any
        profile: any;
    
        highestloaneligible:number;
        repaymentdate:any;
         interest: number;
        amountpayable:any;
        loanamount:number;
        loantenor:any;
        loanday:string
        today=new Date
        totalinterest:number
        amountpayableRO:number
        totalinterestRU:any
  
  
        banknameholder: string;
        accountnumberholder: string;


         creditScore:number;

         isEnabled: boolean;
         pay: any;
         creditScorevalue: number;
         employmentstatusholder:string
         workindustryholder:string
         jobtitleholder:string

         datetofbirthholder: any;
 
         datetofbirth: any;

         title = '';
         emailaddress: any;
    
          onload(){
      
            this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
            this.data = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.user;
            
            }
           });

            }
             options: PaystackOptions = {
             amount: 50000,
            // //email: 'user@mail.com',
            //  email:  document.getElementById(email).value
             email: this.data.emailaddress,
   
            ref: `${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10e10)}`,
            currency:"NGN"
    
              } 
 
             constructor(private myservice:DataitemsService,private route: 
             ActivatedRoute,public loadingController: LoadingController,private router: 
             Router,private afs:AngularFirestore, public alertCtrl: AlertController,public 
             db: AngularFirestore ) {}
              // constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,private 
              afs:AngularFirestore, public alertCtrl: AlertController,public db: 
          AngularFirestore ) {}
            
  
            async ngOnInit() {
              // onload(){
        
               this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
               if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
                this.data = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.user;
                 }
                  });
              //this.myservice.datasomething();
                   // this.myservice.profilesomething();
                this.user = {

                 firstname: this.data.firstname,
                lastname: this.data.lastname,
                phonenumber:this.data.phonenumber,
                salaryrange:this.data.salaryrange,
                emailaddress:this.data.emailaddress
                 }
        
            let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
               state: {
               user: this.user
               }
              };
    
               }
           }
```

this is the code on paystackpayment.module.ts:

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
   import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
   import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
   import { PaystackpaymentPage } from './paystackpayment.page';
   import { Angular4PaystackModule } from 'angular4-paystack';

   import { PaystackpaymentPageRoutingModule } from './paystackpayment-routing.module';


   @NgModule({

     imports: [
       Angular4PaystackModule.forRoot('***********************'),
       CommonModule,
       FormsModule,
       IonicModule,
       PaystackpaymentPageRoutingModule
       ],
       declarations: [PaystackpaymentPage]
    })
   export class PaystackpaymentPageModule {
    }
```

and on my paystackpayment.html I have:

```
  <ion-header [translucent]="true">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>
        Blank
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
    <ion-header collapse="condense">
       <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title size="large">Blank</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <div id="container">
      <button
      angular4-paystack
      [paystackOptions]="options"
      (paymentInit)="paymentInit()"
      (onClose)="paymentCancel()"
      (callback)="paymentDone($event)"
     >
      Pay with Paystack
    </button>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
```